# Converting <br /> into a new line for use in a text area

Tags: php, html

If I have a variable:

```
$var1 = "Line 1 info blah blah <br /> Line 2 info blah blah";
```

And a text area:

```
<textarea>echo $var1</textarea>
```

How can I get the text area to display a new line instead of displaying the text on a single like with a `<br />` in it?

**Edit:** I have tried the following:

```
<textarea class="hobbieTalk" id="hobbieTalk" name="hobbieTalk" cols="35" rows="5" onchange="contentHandler('userInterests',this.id,this.value,0)"><?php

$convert=$_SESSION["hobbieTalk"];
$convert = str_replace("<br />", "\n", $convert);
echo $convert;

?></textarea>
```

However the text area still contains the `br` tags in the lines.

Comment: [I found this answer to be useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494754/opposite-of-nl2br-is-it-str-replace) Didn't seem to match up with any of the answers above.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?php
    $text = "Hello <br /> Hello again <br> Hello again again <br/> Goodbye <BR>";
    $breaks = array("<br />","<br>","<br/>");  
    $text = str_ireplace($breaks, "\r\n", $text);  
?>  
<textarea><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: thank you everyone: please note if you store this string in your db using converted html tags you must put: $breaks = array("<br />","<br>","<br/>","<br />","&lt;br /&gt;","&lt;br/&gt;","&lt;br&gt;");     cheers all

Comment: $text = str_ireplace($breaks, "", $text); worked better for me! :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld for this $text = str_ireplace($breaks, "", $text);  your can use `strip_tags($text)`

Comment: @Naumov this will strip all tags from string, not only $breaks

Comment: @ManuelDallaLana In question write what you need echo string in `<textarea><?php echo $var1 ?></textarea>` it means hi need only text no html entities.

Comment: When writing text file, you can use PHP_EOL (it will add \r\n or \n depending on the platform(windows or linux)

     $text = str_ireplace($breaks, PHP_EOL, $text);

Comment: It's a bad idea to replace HTML tags as if they are text constants. What if we get `<   br>` or `<br class="unexpected">`

Answer (score 18):

i am use following construction to convert back nl2br

```
function br2nl( $input ) {
    return preg_replace('/<br\s?\/?>/ius', "\n", str_replace("\n","",str_replace("\r","", htmlspecialchars_decode($input))));
}
```

here i replaced `\n` and `\r` symbols from $input because nl2br dosen't remove them and this causes wrong output with `\n\n` or `\r<br>`.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @Mobilpadde is nice. But this is my solution with regex using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) which might be faster according to my tests.

`echo preg_replace('/<br\s?\/?>/i', "\r\n", "testing<br/><br /><BR><br>");`

```
function function_one() {
    preg_replace('/<br\s?\/?>/i', "\r\n", "testing<br/><br /><BR><br>");
}

function function_two() {
    str_ireplace(['<br />','<br>','<br/>'], "\r\n", "testing<br/><br /><BR><br>");
}

function benchmark() {
    $count = 10000000;
    $before = microtime(true);

    for ($i=0 ; $i<$count; $i++) {
        function_one();
    }

    $after = microtime(true);
    echo ($after-$before)/$i . " sec/function one\n";



    $before = microtime(true);

    for ($i=0 ; $i<$count; $i++) {
        function_two();
    }

    $after = microtime(true);
    echo ($after-$before)/$i . " sec/function two\n";
}
benchmark();
```

Results:

```
1.1471637010574E-6 sec/function one (preg_replace)
1.6027762889862E-6 sec/function two (str_ireplace)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach.

```
class orbisius_custom_string {
    /**
     * The reverse of nl2br. Handles <br/> <br/> <br />
     * usage: orbisius_custom_string::br2nl('Your buffer goes here ...');
     * @param str $buff
     * @return str
     * @author Slavi Marinov | http://orbisius.com
     */
    public static function br2nl($buff = '') {
        $buff = preg_replace('#<br[/\s]*>#si', "\n", $buff);
        $buff = trim($buff);

        return $buff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: previous answer was backwards of what you wanted.  Use str_replace.
replace `<br>` with \n

```
echo str_replace('<br>', "\n", $var1);
```

Comment: It does the opposite, turns all new line characters into br tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$var1 = "Line 1 info blah blah <br /> Line 2 info blah blah";
$var1 = str_replace("<br />", "\n", $var1);

?>

<textarea><?php echo $var1; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: str_replace("<br />", "\n", $var1) - fails it still produced <br /> outputs

Comment: Are you setting $var1 equal to the? So:
$var1 = str_replace("<br />", "\n", $var1);

Comment: No, I don't. It creates a new line man, it's just that your textarea isn't being rendered in codepad.

Comment: No, my example in CodePad does work. Look at your example again.

Comment: Codepad does not render a textarea, do you see a textarea in the output or just the tags <textarea> ? 
http://screencast.com/t/BklEkcjNx

Comment: <textarea class="hobbieTalk" id="hobbieTalk" name="hobbieTalk" cols="35" rows="5" onchange="contentHandler('userInterests',this.id,this.value,0)"><?php 
     $convert = str_replace("<br />", "\n", $_SESSION["hobbieTalk"]); echo $convert; ?></textarea> - this still fails

Comment: Obviously, you are not looking closely at your example, since your linked image example demonstrates you have fixed the error. :)

Comment: @Jared - The image example shows the exact code copied from your codepad link.

Comment: @Dan - Yes, but it's NOT the same from your example. My code works, yours above in the answer does not.

Comment: line1 info<br />line 2 info from my above example this is what is displayed in my textarea still

Comment: @Jared - Fixed for your awesomeness. It was a guide in the right direction, not copy/paste win.

Comment: @Dan - Just pay attention to details. What's in the answer is what matters. @someguy - Please edit your answer and put your actual code in it.

Comment: @Dan - Just an FYI, you were missing double quotes around your `\n`. I appreciate your sarcasm, but here is what your answer said verbatim: http://codepad.org/AA4GZ2jx A cursory glance at the actual answer code should have told you this. :)