# Replace <br> tags white line break IN STRING

Tags: php, replace

I'm trying to replace the tags `<br/>` and `<br>` in my string

this is the code that I found on the web, but this prints "\n" as a text, and I need a new line break

```
$fldtextArea_name = str_replace("<br>", "\n", $fldtextArea_name);
```

Comment: Here is a good answer for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6009770/910862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$fldtextArea_name = str_replace("<br>", "\n", $fldtextArea_name); 
echo "<pre>" . $fldtextArea_name . "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

That code works perfect. when you

```
echo $fldtextArea_name;
```

it works ok... Are you sure you did not wrote '\n' instead of (correctly) "\n"  ? for instance:

```
$fld = str_replace("<br>", "\n", "aaa<br>bbbb<br>ccc<br>");
echo $fld;
```

will output :

```
aaa bbbb ccc
```

on the browser and if you look at the page source you will see:

```
aaa
bbbb
ccc
```