# Checkbox inside textarea

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create check boxes inside textarea component? I am using simple html and css. I know we can do with tables. But can we do it in textarea?

Comment: It is not possible textarea is self an input field, What you want to achieve?

Comment: `The HTML <textarea> element represents a multi-line plain-text editing control.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: do you mean adding checkbox values to textarea

Comment: Straight answer... no, not possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No as you cannot use Rendered HTML within a `<textarea>`, it's impossible to create a checkbox inside a textarea.

But you could use a `<div contenteditable="true">`, to accomplish your goal. See also: [Can I embed HTML formatting inside of a <textarea> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580247/can-i-embed-html-formatting-inside-of-a-textarea-tag) and [Convert html tag in textarea to rich text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785845/convert-html-tag-in-textarea-to-rich-text)