# Converting <br /> into a new line for textarea makes more new line

Tags: html, textarea, newline

I am converting `<br/>` into new line by following [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004343/converting-br-into-a-new-line-for-use-in-a-text-area).

I am using

```
<textarea name="newtext" style="margin: 0px; width: 550px; height: 120px;"><?php echo str_replace("<br />", "\r\n", $posttext['text']); ?></textarea>
```

for me.
My code is for a edittext field.

My problem is when I am editing text like

`hi
I am
here`

It is showing

```
hi

I am

here
```

And when I re-editing this it comes like

```
hi



I am



here
```

What I need to do to solve this?
Here one thing to mention that when I am saving this text I am using

```
$texttrim = trim($_POST['newtext']);
$newtexts = nl2br($texttrim);
```

Comment: Did you tryied to remove `\r` ? I already used something similar to add some line-breaks in a `<textarea></textarea>` and the use of these both was a problem since it added one more line-breaks.

Comment: First I tried without \r. But result was same,