# str_ireplace is adding a <br> on webserver (localhost is working)

Tags: php

I want to colorize the keywords of my Text-Output. I am pulling the keywords out of the DB. Running a loop and using this function to change the code:

```
str_ireplace($row['keyword'], "<span class=\"".$row['mycolor']."\">".$row['keyword']."</span>", $_POST['mytext'])
```

My localhost is working fine. The result is for example this:

```
more text... <span class="red">my keyword</span> more text...
```

The exact same file with the exact same "keyword"-DB is producing this in the www:

```
more text... <span class="red<br ></span>">my keyword</span> more text...
```

I dont understand why the webserver is adding the `<br ></span>` on the wrong position.

Do you have any clues?

I updated the keywords-CSV file (utf-8) before and uploaded it to the DB. I am doin gthis the last two years. But now there is the strange `<br >`.

Comment: if you came from windows and are now on Linux try using dos2unix (to convert line endings) https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix

Comment: Hi, I am not converting a TextFIle. I am changing html code via str_ireplace which I got out of my DB.

Comment: and when you look at the row in the db there is no <br> or did it upload with a <br> ?

Comment: There is no <br>. I am using a xls file fo rall my keywords. After that I converting the file into a csv file (utf-8) and uploading it into my DB. There are no <br> at all. In the past this procedure worked fine.

Comment: maybe this will help, looks like maybe a function is converting /r/n  into <br> somewhere in your flow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514698/str-ireplace-or-preg-replace-replaced-break-tag-into-r-n

Comment: But it is all working on my localhost. Thats the strange thing.