# How to save a text string with line breaks to a MySQL database text field using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, line-breaks

In SugarCRM I have a Textarea field that I am trying to save data to with line breaks.

IF I insert `<br>` tags, then they show up as text break tags.   If I try something like `\n` then it also shows up as text.

Now if I go into SugarCRM and edit a record, I can type in text and make a linebreak.  Save the record and view it again and the line breaks show up as I would want them to!

I am trying to save data with line breaks to the same field from a remote API script.

I went into the Database with phpMyAdmin to see how the field looked and here it is...

The first 3 lines have proper line breaks which I made inside SugarCRM editing a record manually.

The line after are from my remote API script where I had saved `<br>` tags into the string.

```
Line 1 Text: ghfghdf
Line 1 Color: #0064FF
Line 1 Font: Architect
Line 2 Text: fghfg<br /> Line 2 Color: #9F00FF<br /> Line 2 Font: Belshaw<br /> Line 3 Text: fghdhdhdf<br /> Line 3 Color: #FF5000<br /> Line 3 Font: Benguiat<br />
```

**Any ideas how I can make my PHP code save a string to this field and have line breaks when viewing it in the database just like the first 3 lines above are?**

Comment: Is this of any help ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2494763/2123530

Comment: I google a little and TinyMCE can be used in SugarCRM so i think that would solve your problem with any text format

Comment: Is the data returned from the API HTML?

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic Thanks for the suggestion and research however I am unable to change the filed type in SugarCRM for this case so I will have to instead modify the output with custom SugarCRM code it seems

Comment: @dbinns66 I am actually inserting data using the API instead of returning it.  SO using PHP I save data into SugarCRM and then view that data inside the actual SugarCRM application when editing and viewing fields.  It seems I will simply have to do some custom code in SUgar for the "view" portion since I cannot modify how it is saved.

Comment: @b.enoit.be that is certainly something I forgot about and I will test it to see if it helps in my situation, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @b.enoit.be That did the trick, thanks so much!  If you post it as an answer I will select it as it is very useful info!

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723917/how-to-save-a-text-string-with-line-breaks-to-a-mysql-database-text-field-using?noredirect=1#comment-47582188), this kind of issue tends to be related to the fact that in [single quoted strings](https://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.single) :

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (\). To specify a literal backslash, double it (\\).
>
> All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the other escape sequences you might be used to, **such as \r or \n**, will be output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.

but in [double quoted strings](https://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.double) :

> PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters
>
> sequence : **\n** then having the meaning of linefeed (LF or 0x0A (10) in ASCII)

So `echo '\n'` will print **\n**
while `echo "\n"` will allow you to have a new line as excepted.

And of course, you also can use `PHP_EOL` to make it cross OS.

Answer (score 1):

Use `PHP_EOL` instead of `<br/`> or `\n`

e.g.

```
$array = array("a","b");
$string = implode(PHP_EOL , $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to store data that has line breaks, you want to use the nl2br() function inside of php before you store the data. I had the same issues before and after months and months of trying different things to get it to work right on a client's site, it was on SO that I found the answer one day.

The key is to convert the data by using nl2br() before you store it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer however if I am to use `nl2br()` then it will add `<br>` tags to my string which is not what I want.  In SUgarCRM when you view a record, if it has `<br>` tags in the string then it shows the tags instead of making them function.

Comment: *"The key is to convert the data by using nl2br() before you store it."*. No. Don't do that. You will regret it later. What if you want to output this text in another format? Put it in a PDF, send it over mail, read and display it in an Android app etc etc? Instead convert the data before you *display* it. Always store data in it's most generic form. As text. Only add markup, escape, force text to uppercase etc etc before *displaying* it. This allows you to use the right markup and escapes for the particular display format instead of mixing it in the data.