# PHP preg_replace() need to match specific field between chars

Tags: php, html, regex

I need help changing the tag `<br>` for a `\n` outside of `HTML`.

I'm trying this in `PHP`:

```
$sub->text = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $sub->text);
```

But it's no working because I have this tags between words, spaces, at beginning of sentences, etc..

Sample:

```
...is not<br>Pyrenees?
```

In this cases I don't know how to match the `<br>`

I obtain this results:

```
1
00:00:14,185 --> 00:00:18,143
Bueno, gràcies Elòdia per la presentació<br>i només dir una prèvia: Trobo que és un encert,


2
00:00:18,184 --> 00:00:23,225
tractant-se de que Andorra és el païs dels<br>Pirineus no? que comencem el Ted x <br>per Andorra amb un alpinista, 


3
00:00:23,265 --> 00:00:27,655
és a dir, algú que comença, que escala <br>muntanyes, que a vegades ens oblidem que aquí hi han muntanyes també per escalar,
```

Anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: "outside of HTML". Can you be more specific? By definition your whole document is HTML, right?

Comment: How it is not working?

Comment: @HamZa , I extract this text from a HTML and writes in a regular .txt file and I don't want this <br> tags, I want new lines

Comment: @Sergi your `preg_replace()` should work on `<br>`. So what isn't working?

Comment: @HamZa, I don't understand why, but I can't get the substitution that I need

Comment: @Sergi The problem might lie somewhere else. I suggest to debug your code using `var_dump()` and inspect the involved variables step by step.

Comment: Maybe the code contains `<br class="newline">` or `<br clear=all>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$html = 'this <br>is<br/>some<br />text <br    />!';
$nl = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $html);
echo $nl;
```

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2494762/631652) for answer.

**OR**

```
str_replace(['<br />', '<br/>', '<br>'],"\n",$foo)
```

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2494758/631652) for answer.

Answer (score 1):

just simply do the string replace `str_replace`, I think its better to use `str_replace` instead of regular expression.

```
    $content = "<body>this is naveen<br></body>";
    $result = str_replace("<br>", "\n", $content);
    echo $result;
```