# PHP send browser content to text file

Tags: php, file, output, ob-start

i generate Header's title and strings with php function,

```
HeaderA
loremipsum

HeaderB
Loremipsum
```

i tried to save this content to txt file with:

```
ob_start();
```

But the main issue is that it will contain eg. :

```
'<br>'
```

I dont want to place html tags in the txt file only just the look of the function's return.

Whats the best way?

i tried with the following:

```
    ob_start();
echo 'HeaderA';
echo '<br>';
echo 'Loremipsum';
echo 'HeaderB';
echo '<br>';
echo 'Loremipsum';
$content=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$ct=strip_tags($content);
echo $ct;

file_put_contents("text.txt",$ct);
```

Well strip_tags does not helped,its remove the br html tag but the text format does not preserved as the desired format

Comment: If I understood correctly you're looking for `strip_tags` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: @TeKo I don't think that's right

Comment: yes strip_tags removes html tags but also 'kill' the desired format

Comment: If you don't want to include the `<br>`-s .. why are you echo-ing them at all?

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398725/using-php-substr-and-strip-tags-while-retaining-formatting-and-without-break

Comment: i need to echo the br tag,its creates the desired format,in the browser it is rendered correctly,now i want the same result in the file as the browser has

Comment: If you're creating the text file contents solely within php replace `echo <br>` with `echo "\n"` for Linux line endings, or `echo "\r\n"`  for Windows line endings. **must use double-quotes (")** Otherwise if your accepting it as a variable, you would need to use something like  [`str_replace(['<br>', '<br/>'], "\n", $content);`](https://3v4l.org/KZ5lp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opposite of nl2br? Is it str\_replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494754/opposite-of-nl2br-is-it-str-replace)

Comment: using echo  nl2br ("kings \n garden"); would be good but does not works inside ob_start nor simple \n\r

Comment: You could go the other way around. You could echo line end chars instead of `<br>`'s and wrap the whole thing in `<pre>` tags that would preserve formatting on the browser side, and would get stripped while writing to file. Dirty, but might be the thing you want to achieve.